# Powershell - Log off all users?

Tags: powershell, logoff

I was previously using a script found [here](http://poshcode.org/3285) for logging off all users, however this does not work on certain versions of Windows 7 (specifically windows 7 home. The quser executable does not exist).

Does anyone else have any suggesions on how I can go about logging off all users? The other alternative I was going to attempt was:

```
(gwmi win32_operatingsystem -computername '.').Win32Shutdown(4)
```

But this seems to only logoff the current user (I would like to log off all of the users).

Comment: Did you ever figure this out using powershell, i had to use VBscript due to the time constraint.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Win32ShutdownTracker method of the WMI Win32_OperatingSystem class. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394057(v=vs.85).aspx

I'm using this in a script against remote computers, and it logs off all users and/or reboots the computer.

Comment: Nice one. Didn't know about that method! If you do a forced log off (code 4) do you know if it logs off all users or just the one running the command? Documentation doesn't specify.

Comment: @Rakha - I'm in an environment where our Win7 boxes are blocked by policy from having multiple logged-on users at a time, so I can't answer this for sure - but given the way we use it (one of our remote management/remote support tools), it _probably_ logs off all users.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's one user at a time here too so that's why i couldn't test it hehe ;)

Comment: @Rakha - The point here is that we use it against _remote_ computers, not our own. When we do, it does what we need - it frees up the computer so that we can do remote maintenance, installations, or Administrator-credentialled troubleshooting, when the user has walked away and is unreachable for us to tell him/her to log off.

Comment: Exactly the same kind of situation over here, except we can't force logoff or people will cry ;)

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use [psshutdown](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897541.aspx) with -o parameter

Comment: That's only the console user, not all users.